# Using multivariable chain rule

Tags: calculus

Let $v(x,y)$ be continuously differentiable function. Let the function $u(s,t)$ be given by 
$$u(s,t)=t^2\cdot v(\ln (t\cdot s),5-4\cdot t).$$
Compute $\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}(s,t)$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} (s,t)$ in terms of $v$ and its partial derivatives.

My solution so far:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}(s,t)&=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}t^2 v(\ln (t s),5-4 t)\\
&=\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\cdot \frac{\partial v}{\partial \ln(t\cdot s)}\cdot \frac{d \ln(t\cdot s)}{ds}\\
&=t^2\cdot \frac{\partial v(\ln (t\cdot s),5-4t)}{\partial \ln (t\cdot s)}\cdot \frac{1}{s}
\end{align*}
Is it correct so far?

Comment: My apologies for my careless typos; I have corrected those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is unclear to me with the last equality possibly wrong (the derivative involving $\log$ is dubious).

The composition process is shown in slow motion as follows:
$$
u: (s,t) \mapsto (\log (ts), 5-4t) =: (x,y) \mapsto v(x,y) =: w \mapsto t^{2}w;
$$
the map $u$ is the composition of three maps.
So by chain rule we have
$$
\nabla u(s,t) = t^{2}\cdot \nabla v(x,y)\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{s} & \frac{1}{t}\\
0 & -4
\end{bmatrix}\\
=
\bigg(
\frac{t^{2}}{s}D_{1}v(x,y),\
tD_{1}v(x,y) - 4t^{2}D_{2}v(x,y) \bigg);
$$
by replacing $(x,y)$ with $(\log (ts), 5-4t)$ we are done.